# How to get responds from onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an activity and an asynctask. I want the progress result in the async task to the activity text view and final result in activity text view. Am stuck in final point that how to send result from both `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()`. Help me out in solving this issue

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
Button b1;
AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> ta;
private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewer);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clicker);

    tv.setText("2");
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
            ta = new TestAsync(getApplicationContext()).execute(val);
        }
    }); 
}

public void callOnEnd() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "TestAsync " + ta.get() + " status " + ta.getStatus());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TestAsync Exception " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

**TestAsync.java**

```
public class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>{

Context context;
private static String TAG = "TestAsync";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

public TestAsync(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + "Reached AsyncTask");
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + "doInBackground");
    int val = params[0], i, res;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
        res = i * val;
        publishProgress(res);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + " onProgressUpdate " + values[0]);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + "onPostExecute " + result);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Implement the `AsyncTask` as a inner class:
   You would be able to access `MainActivity.this` from within `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostUpdate()`. You would be able to call somthing like this.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
       MainActivity.this.tv.setText("my result is: " + result);
   }
   ```
2. You could create some sort of interface in your `MainActivity` that you pass to your `AsyncTask` to call it from within these methods.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       // all your code

       public void onResult(Integer result) {
           tv.setText("my result is: " + result);
       }
   }
   ```

   And in your `AsyncTask`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
       ((MainActivity) context).onResult(result);
   }
   ```

   You need to create the `TestAsync()` with `MainActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. Otherwise, the cast will fail.

   A proper `interface` would be nicer, but you get the idea.

Comment: Both are in 2 diff class files. So how should i try to access the textView from the asynctask onPostExecute()

Comment: See my second option: create a method in `MainActivity` and call it from the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Sorry, I just found a copy+past error in the answer. fixed it a second ago.

Comment: Had to add an other note at the bottom, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: 2 errors
1. return type required for onResult()
2. ClassCastException in onPostExecute ((MainActivity) context)....

Comment: fixed the return code. that's the downside of writing code in the browser.. but you should be able to fix these things yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do in onProgressUpdate and onPostUpdate, will be posted directly to UIThread. Just write your logic inside these two functions and you can access any component of UI thread in these two functions.

Comment: Can u pls provide me 1 code to display the result in onProgressUpdate() to the TextView that is in activity.

Comment: Directly write the value in Textview in your onProgessUpdate.

Comment: Both are in 2 diff class files. How can i get the object of textview in async task

Comment: I have updated my answer. Probably to make it simple, you can write your asynctask in same file. Else there are ways to access activity element in another class using its instance